# GGPLOT2: how to plot specific selections inthe ggplot() script

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a peak into a large dataset named `P`, where there are 10 concessionaries (`CS`) that have different shops (`SHP`) with several numeric values. The dataset lists them ordered by week (`WK`) 2 tm 52. It creates a large file. A peak into just the 6 first rows:

```
WK,MND,CS,SHP,RevCY,RevLY,TCY,TLY,ACY,ALY
=========================================
2,JAN,AAA,AAA Shop 1,16834,16686,1837,1983,2853,3002 

2,JAN,AAA,AAA Shop 2,95919,114696,9742,11813,20521,24673

2,JAN,BBB, BBB shop 1,93428,92212,7647,7857,18436,17984

2,JAN,BBB, BBB Shop 2,30600,35831,2748,3063,5579,6408

2,JAN,CCC, CCC Shop 1, 65229,78761,6074,7172,13852,16706

2,JAN,CCC, CCC Shop 2,465,754,73,118,92,162
```

I have difficulties plotting just the values that concern fi `SHP==AAA`.

```
p <- ggplot(P, aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

This is plotting all shops and all `CS`. So the underlying question is to understand how I can plot only the shops (`SHP`) from `CS=AAA`. Let's say with the weeks (`WK`) on the x-axis and `RevCY` on the y-axis in the `ggplot() + geom_bar(stat="identity")` code.

Is this the right direction?:

```
p <- ggplot(P[P$CS=="AAA"], aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

So without creating all kinds of subsets and straight into the `ggplot()` code.
Hope my question is clear.

Comment: By the way, `t` is not very good name for `data.frame` as far as it is function `t()` (matrix transpose).

Comment: @redmode point taken. I renamed it to P. Can you still help me?

Comment: Isn't answer from Sven Hohenstein helpful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
ggplot(t, aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(data=subset(t,CS=="AAA"),stat="identity")
```

Comment: Yes very much. I will practise with this. Thanx

Answer (score 4):

To extract certain rows from your data frame `t`, you have to use

```
t[t$CS == "AAA", ]
```

instead of `t[t$CS == "AAA"]`. The latter syntax is used to select columns.

The plot command:

```
p <- ggplot(t[t$CS == "AAA", ], aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I suppose you want to add some arguments to produce multiple bars per `WK` instead of a single stacked bar:

```
p <- ggplot(t[t$CS == "AAA", ], aes(as.factor(WK), RevCY)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(group = RevCY), position = "dodge")
```

Comment: thanks. Bur if I want to select 2 or more CS? The following won't work: >ggplot(t[t$CS == "AAA"& "BBB", ], aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(group = RevCY), position = "dodge")

Comment: @user3214508 If you want to compare a variable with multiple values, you have to use `%in%`. For your example: `t$CS %in% c("AAA", "BBB")`.

Comment: If i Type: >ggplot(t[t$CS %in% C("AAA","BBB"), ], aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(group=RevCY), position="dodge") I get an error: "Error in C("AAA", "BBB") : object not interpretable as a factor" .

Comment: @user3214508 Why did you use a capital `C` when my code includes a lowercase `c`?

Comment: I meant c. Typing >ggplot(t[t$CS %in% c("AAA","BBB"), ], aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(group=RevCY), position="dodge") gives error: Error: unexpected '>' in ">"

Comment: @user3214508 Try `ggplot(t[t$CS %in% c("AAA","BBB"), ], aes(WK, RevCY)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(group=RevCY), position="dodge")`.

Comment: @sven, your solution is using base-r, right? Do you think it's faster than subset() when used within a ggplot?